# How to set badge count in iOS 10 for pushnotification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, appdelegate

I want to set badge count on app icon when notification recieved.Below method is called when notification is recieved.But the badge count does not set.

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        var userData = userInfo as NSDictionary? as? [AnyHashable: Any] ?? [:]
        var aps  = userData["aps"] as! NSDictionary
        var badge = aps["badge"]
        print("data is \(badge!)")
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge! as! Int
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
          content.badge = 10
        } else {
          // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        // your badge count
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually in iOS 10 these two methods are called:

If the app is in the foreground:

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
               willPresent notification: UNNotification, 
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

If the app is in the background:

```
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

---

You need to get the `content` of the `request` of the `notification`

- foreground method

  ```
  let content = notification.request.content
  ```
- background method

  ```
  let content = response.notification.request.content
  ```

The badge number is in the property `badge` of `content`

```
let badgeNumber = content.badge as! Int
```

Comment: @Kiranjadhav Please stop posting this comment on any related thread you can find. It can't be adequately answered in comments, and you are pinging many users, which can be annoying. Please ask a new question instead.

Comment: @vadian,,,
i am trying from few days but i don't get proper solution over it, if possible please try to explain me other wise no problem thanks....!

Comment: Neither of those are called.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the authorization for badge.I added badge in code

```
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
        // actions based on whether notifications were authorized or not
      }
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

I added this in `didFinishLaunchWithOptions`